# Is it possible with c#.net to programmatically check if certain .com domain exists?

Tags: c#, .net, dns

Is there someway, using c# code, to query an api, services, or whatever online service there are to check if a .com domain is taken already? I have been doing it manually since a month and I have not found a domain name for my website)

Comment: The GoDaddy API might be a good place to start. https://developer.godaddy.com/

Comment: You can use WHOIS api to see his database, but it's not free: https://whois.whoisxmlapi.com/documentation/making-requests

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can query the api at developer.godaddy.com.

Please see the complete list of available api below.
https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/available

Exact api which you can use.
[image]